# Mac won't won't boot up after trying to update latest OS

Tags: reboot

Mac won't won't boot up after trying to update to the latest OS, when rebooting in recovery mode, the utilities option to reinstall the OS shows that there's not enough space to update the OS, but I can't access my desktop to try and use an external hard drive to try and remove some files to free up space

Comment: What happens when you try to boot?

Comment: What Mac? how much space do you have left? you updating to Big Sur, or the Monterey beta?

Comment: Hi Val, be sure to edit all details needed to answer the question into the body of the question. Comments help to understand what needs improving in the body of the post.

Comment: as for space left on my Mac I have 7gb but I need 12gb but now I'm unable to try and boot up in recovery mode all it does is just show me a screen with the apple logo and the progress bar